# Render remote PNG image in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, get, png

I am developing an AngularJS application which displays a PNG image retrieved from a server.

If I put the URL (see below) in the browser I can see the image just fine. However, if I want to retrieve such image from my Angular application I cannot manage to display it (although I do receive the data!).

The JS code is the following:

```
$scope.receivedImage = null;

var url = 'https://subdomain.mydomain.uk/img?latitude=55.57&longitude=-5.16&extent=2000';

$http(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'image/png'
        }
    }
).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.receivedImage = data;
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
        console.error(response);
    }
);
```

The problem is that I cannot see the image that is retrieved. To understand better the situation I put in the HTML page the following code:

```
<div ng-show="receivedImage">
    <pre>{{receivedImage}}</pre>
    <img data-ng-src="{{receivedImage}}" />
    <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;{{receivedImage}}" />
</div>
```

The '' shows something like

> �PNG IHDR�R9�%IDATx��̱    ������ �2��'��j�Z�V��w����LxIEND�B`�

The first '' does not show anything.

The second '' shows an image icon and throws in console an error:

> GET
>   data:image/png;%EF%BF%BDPNG%1A%00%00%00IHDR%00%00%00%1E%00%00%00%1E%08%02%0…%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDL%0E%17x%00%00%00%00IEND%EF%BF%BDB`%EF%BF%BD
>   net::ERR_INVALID_URL

How can I render this image correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the ng-src attribute to a variable that is the url.

```
$scope.url = 'https://subdomain.mydomain.uk/img?latitude=55.57&longitude=-5.16&extent=2000';
```

and in the markup

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" />
```

Comment: Wow, it works! So there is no need whatsoever to do a HTTP GET request! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the url is unprotected then the approach from [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800469/anthony) helps a lot. For my use-case where the URL was protected i had to go with the below approach. In this case i had to inject the authentication headers by overriding angular's http authentication interceptors for accessing the protected URL.

```
    // http call inside a service under a function named getImage()
    $http(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'YOUR_PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL',
            // This is required for getting your data as buffer array
            {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            }
        }
    ).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.error(response);
        }
    );
```

Inside your controller or directive the data that comes from the above call has to be handled like so:

```
// Function to get the image from the server
var handleImage = function(){
    MyHttpService.getImage()
    .then(function(response){
      // Can be used within ng-src fro displaying image
      $scope.receivedImage = 'data:image/png;base64,'+_arrayBufferToBase64(response);
    }, function(error){
      console.error(error);
    });
};

// Convert the buffer to base64
var _arrayBufferToBase64 = function( buffer ) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        console.log(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
        }
        return window.btoa( binary );
      };
```

Hope this helps someone who is trying to access the resource from a protected resource URI.